# Is there an address book for Geary

Tags: pantheon-mail

I would like to import my contacts from my android phone address book.

I have a VCF file with multiple contacts along with their photos.

Is there an address book that is part of or can be integrated into Geary?

Terry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this newsletter post](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/geary-list/2015-February/msg00025.html), contact sync for Geary was planned but never implemented. The original developers of Geary shut down, but the Elementary team has [forked Geary](https://twitter.com/elementary/status/668677459307433985) and continues to develop the app.

Elementary at one point had a contact manager called Dexter, but this app was [pulled until it could be revamped](http://old.elementary.io/answers/why-no-dexter). The project still exists and is [active in Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/dexter-contacts).

[Gnome Contacts](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Contacts) would probably work well on Elementary, but it doesn't currently integrate with Geary.

Long story short: there's not currently a contact manager that integrates with Geary, but it could definitely happen in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer.  

eOS looks like an excellent OS for non-technical people but the lack of a contact manager looks like a deal breaker to me.

I will definitely keep an eye on this and hopefully in the near future we will see a contact manager.

Comment: Glad it helped! I'd love to see a contact manager too. If you're interested in trying another email app, Thunderbird and Evolution both have built-in contact managers. I don't find them to be as elegant as Geary, but they'd probably be more robust.

Answer (score 2):

I agree this would a be a must-have feature for elementary OS, but in the meantime I use **Evolution app** to manage my email and it has a built-in feature to manage addresses books (due to gnome-contacts, which uses evolution-data-server). So I recommend you to use it instead of pantheon mail until elementary develops its own address book.